# What Python script will find the locations of every backslash inside of an HTML tag and replace the backslash with a forward slash?

Tags: python, html, regex

Input:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>This is a title</title>
  <\head>
  <body>
    <div>
        <p>H/e/l/l/o \a\b\c\d\e\f\gw/o/r/l/d!</p>
    </div>
  <\body>
<\html>
```

Output:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>This is a title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
        <p>H/e/l/l/o \a\b\c\d\e\f\gw/o/r/l/d!</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

We do not want to replace every single forward slash `\` with backslash `/`.  Some of the backslashes are *intended* to be backslashes. We wish only to replace backslash `\` with forward slash `/` if the backslash `\` is inside of a misspelled HTML tag such as `<\kbd>`.

Comment: `html = html.replace(r'<\', '/>')`

Comment: In general it's better to fix problem like this _upstream_ - find out where the broken "HTML" is coming from, and fix _that_. Regex is [famously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3001761) not a tool for dealing with even well-formed HTML.

Comment: How about self-contained tags that are in error `<tag\>` ?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Don't know why my comment got deleted. Can you explain how to fix malformed HTML ? And Regex _is famously used to parse HTML._ https://regex101.com/r/9pG81b/1 https://regex101.com/r/iR1YbV/1 Thousands of times here on SO.

Comment: I was going to give you a regex solution but as stated in my comment that got deleted ...

Answer (score 0):

you can use the folloing pattern:

```
(?<=<)\\(?=.*?>)
```

[code online](https://ideone.com/Awty69)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions

```
import re


def convert_backslash(text):
    return re.sub(r'<\\', r'</', text, re.MULTILINE)
```

Text input must be a raw string like r"..."

```
text_input = r"""
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
  <head>
    <title>This is a title</title>
  <\head>
  <body>
    <div>
        <p>H/e/l/l/o \a\b\c\d\e\f\gw/o/r/l/d!</p>
    </div>
  <\body>
<\html>"""

print(convert_backslash(text_input))
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>This is a title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
        <p>H/e/l/l/o \a\b\c\d\e\f\gw/o/r/l/d!</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```